# reloadRowsAtIndexPaths with Animation - Doesn't animate the first time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a single cell that is normally 60pt high. When tapped, this cell expands to 160pt and exposes a label with more text.

When I tap the cell, didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called, and in there I call:

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

This works fine ONLY after the first tap. The first time I tap the cell, it will immediately expand to 160pt without any animation. Every successive tap will correctly animate the cell between the two heights.

Anyone experience this?